# More efficient plotting with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset `df` that looks like the following:

```
# A tibble: 35,809,246 x 5
    time  conc          t factor     x
   <int> <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
 1    25  555. 0          1       174.
 2    25  555. 0.00000488 1       174.
 3    25  555. 0.00000977 1       174.
 4    25  555. 0.0000146  1       174.
 5    25  555. 0.0000195  1       174.
 6    25  555. 0.0000244  1       174.
 7    25  555. 0.0000293  1       174.
 8    25  555. 0.0000342  1       174.
 9    25  555. 0.0000391  1       174.
10    25  555. 0.0000469  1       174.
# ... with 35,809,236 more rows
```

The column `time` is continuous with `100` unique values. `factor` is a factor with `22` levels. I want to do the following plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = t)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = x, color = time)) +
  facet_wrap(~factor, ncol = 2, scales = "free_y",
             labeller = labeller(factor = factorNames)) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = rel(0.5)))
```

However, it takes more than 30 mins to plot and similar time to save. Therefore, it's quite prohibitive to edit the code and redo the plot in terms of time cost. Is there any way to make this plotting more efficient? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `geom_bin2d()` instead of `geom_line()`! https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bin2d.html

Comment: Are you sure you need to be plotting all those points? Each of 22 facets has 100 lines with an average of 16000+ points per line; this means there is no way a single point is getting a distinct pixel. Resampling to a lower `t` density will probably speed up plotting and not produce any plot that is clearly different. Alternatively use `geom_smooth` or do some summary beforehand if the lines are noisy

Comment: Thanks @CalumYou. Could you please explain  what you mean with `Resampling to a lower t density`. I'm actually not interested in all points but in lines which are not noisy as they are products of a deterministic simulation

Comment: One option would be to use `ggplot(df %>% dplyr::sample_n(1E5), aes(x = t)) +` to see what a representative sample of 100,000 data points would look like.

Comment: If you're looking to highlight the "lines which are not noisy," you might do some more calculations first to identify noise, as you define it. Maybe you're looking for a smoothing function or a rolling average. In any case, ggplot will not be performant beyond something like 100k / 1M data points, so it makes sense to do some filtering first.

Comment: I highly recommend (1) assign plot to a variable: `p <- ggplot()`, (2) save directly to png: `ggsave("plot.png", p, width=10, height=10, dpi=300)`. That alone will cut the time by half or more.

Comment: @AbdallahAtef `geom_line` just draws straight lines between points. I mean that if you have (say) four such lines within the space of one pixel (because four x values lie in that range) the graphics device cannot draw them all and they still have to be calculated. Try `sample_n` as per Jon's advice

Comment: @bdemarest That really helped. and sampling as  per CalumYou and JonSpring was good as well. Thanks all